# linux find command - wholename vs path

Tags: linux, gnu

Is there any difference between the two parameters?

If not, what's the reason there's two parameter names that do exactly the same thing?

Comment: @melpomene This has to do with shell scripting. When combining a sequence of command invocations into a script file, one must know the effect of the various options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name ‘-wholename’ is GNU-specific, but ‘-path’ is more portable; it is supported by HP-UX find and is part of the POSIX 2008 standard.

Examples given at:
https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html